# which are the correct answers?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let$\{a_n\}_{n ≥ 1}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that

$$a_1 >a_2>a_3>...$$  then which of the following are always true ?

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=0$
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges
4. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2}$ converges

I suppose all answers are true. Then am I right?

Comment: Only some of the answers are true.

Comment: You are not right. Two of the statements are true and two are not.

Comment: Could you explain why you think they are all correct?  Then we can discuss where you have and haven't gone wrong.

Comment: I thought any monotonic strictly decreasing sequence converges to 0 only , there I was wrong, I got it

Comment: That still doesn't save you for number 3 - see @Clement C.'s example.  For a series to converge, the sequence has to converge to zero *faster than the harmonic sequence*.

Comment: ya ya I was wrong, afterall thanks a lot

Comment: @Unwisdom: actually, faster than the harmonic sequence is not enough: there are infinitely many positive sequences of that type for which the series diverges to infinity (consider $$a_n=\frac{1}{n(\ln n)(\ln \ln n)(\ln^{(3)} n)\cdots (\ln^{(k)} n)}$$ for any fixed integer $k$)

Comment: Indeed.  But *faster than the harmonic sequence* is a necessary condition, and is generally sufficient for those examples simple enough that one can eyeball them.  Or at least, simple enough for me to eyeball!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. False. Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n}+1\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$.
2. True. $0< \frac{a_n}{n} < \frac{a_1}{n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$ (as $a_1$ is just a constant).
3. False. Take $a_n=\frac{1}{\ln n}$.
4. True. By comparison: $0< \frac{a_n}{n^2} < \frac{a_1}{n^2}$, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: Tiny quibble: For (3) you need to make sure you don't start with $a_1=\infty$. Besides, a better example might just be the example you gave for (1) again.  Then the sequence $a_{n}/n$ is bounded below by the harmonic sequence, and the series must diverge by comparison.

Comment: I agree with the quibble -- I wondered whether I should have gone for $a_n=\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$, but it was slightly less ''instructive'' (remembering that the series $\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges is quite useful). I should have written $$a_n=\begin{cases}0 & n=1 \\ \frac{1}{\ln n} & n\geq 2\end{cases}$$ (but was lazy)

Comment: And I retract my comment regarding (3).  Your thinking about the usefulness of $\sum\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ as an example has been fully vindicated!